# Default value of an @input with a function defined

Tags: angular

I would like to put default value "checked" to a mat-checkbox

```
@Input() set parkings(checked:boolean){
    //stuff
  }
```

And my HTML code

```
<mat-checkbox checked [(ngModel)]="parkings">Parkings</mat-checkbox>
```

I would like to put it checked by default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `get`.

```
private _parkings: boolean = true;
get parkings(): boolean {
  return this._parkings;
}
set parkings(checked: boolean) {
  // stuff to set _parkings.
}
```